# Is it ever explained what Area X actually is?

Tags: soft-sci-fi, annihilation

Is it ever explained what Area X actually is? I don't need to know details as I'm still reading it. But I'm into it enough that I'm feeling like the book/series is going to leave a lot of unanswered questions.

Do we ever find out or is it like the ending of 'Lost'?

Comment: Presumably it's next to Area IX and a little way over from Area XI

Comment: JimDel, I *really* enjoyed the trilogy. I do not want to spoiler things, so I will say that book three provides lots of satisfying resolution to the series, and, at the same time, does so while maintaining ambiguity w/r/t interpretation of Area X. I think a major strength of Vandermeer's with this series of novellas was his ability to commit to the truly and ineffably weird—to human incomprehensibility—without resorting to rapidly-boring surrealism, or to pat answers. Area X results from encountering something with strong limits on comprehensibility... meaning strong limits. :) YMMV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking through various interviews with Vandermeer, he suggests that no character really gets what Area X really is:

From an [interview with Wired.com](https://www.wired.com/2016/11/wired-book-club-jeff-vandermeer-interview/)

> I could have very easily tied off the Southern Reach trilogy in a traditional way, but the fact of the matter is I wanted to explore something that's beyond human comprehension and requires dealing with the irrationality of the human mind and the irrationality of institutions. It would've been completely antithetical to the whole idea to have traditional closure. A lot of pieces to the puzzle are revealed in Acceptance, but no one character has a total eureka moment.

So that suggests that nobody in the books has a real clue what Area X is, so it's not going to be explained. He does admit it being drawn heavily from his hiking experiences in St. Marks Refuge, however, and that it is kind of an alternate Earth setting.

> **It also helped that you drew heavily from St. Marks National Wildlife Refuge, right?**
>
> I've hiked there since around '92. Area X was basically a place I already knew. You don't have to worry about the setting; you just kind of relax into it.
>
> **Were you thinking these books take place essentially in our world?**
>
> I was thinking, like, 10-seconds-in-the-future alternate Earth, in a sense. I kept trying to apply real-world names to things, and it just didn't work. I needed a certain distance and a universality for this that wasn't going to work if you say this is North Florida, for example.